# Can not convert Tuple of Tuple to Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I was trying to convert a tuple of tuple to dictionary but it doesn't give me the correct value.

```
t = ((1,1),(1,10),(1,100),(1,1000),(2,2),(2,20),(2,200),(2,2000),(3,3), 
    (3,30),(3,300),(3,3000),(4,4),(4,40),(4,400),(4,4000))
d = dict(t)
```

doing this gives me a value of

```
d = {1:1000,2:2000,3:3000,4:4000}
```

where as if i try to interchange the values of key value pair it gives all the value like

```
d = dict((x,y) for y,x in t)
d = {1:1,10:1,100:1,1000:1,2:2,20:2,200:2,2000:2,} etc
```

what i want is

```
 d = {1:1,1:10,1:100,1:1000,2:2,2:20,2:200,2:2000...... 4:4000}
```

Comment: Do you think it makes sense for a dictionary to have more than one entry with the same key?

Comment: It wanted to know if there was a way to convert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python dictionaries don't support duplicate keys.

Instead, you can map multiple values(a list) to the same key with a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

t = ((1,1),(1,10),(1,100),(1,1000),(2,2),(2,20),(2,200),(2,2000),(3,3), 
     (3,30),(3,300),(3,3000),(4,4),(4,40),(4,400),(4,4000))

d = defaultdict(list)
for x, y in t:
    d[x].append(y)

print(d)
```

Which gives the following dictionary:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [1, 10, 100, 1000], 2: [2, 20, 200, 2000], 3: [3, 30, 300, 3000], 4: [4, 40, 400, 4000]})
```

**Note:** `defaultdict()` is just a subclass of the built-in `dict` class, so you can treat it the same as a normal dictionary.

If you prefer to use no libraries, [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) is also an option:

```
t = ((1,1),(1,10),(1,100),(1,1000),(2,2),(2,20),(2,200),(2,2000),(3,3), 
     (3,30),(3,300),(3,3000),(4,4),(4,40),(4,400),(4,4000))

d = {}
for x, y in t:
    d.setdefault(x, []).append(y)

print(d)
# {1: [1, 10, 100, 1000], 2: [2, 20, 200, 2000], 3: [3, 30, 300, 3000], 4: [4, 40, 400, 4000]}
```